# Flutter + Firebase - Upload Image File to Storage

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload an image file which I have got using imagepicker.

```
updatePhoto(user, File imageFile) async {
  FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
  Reference ref = storage.ref().child('user/profile/${user.uid}');
  UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(imageFile);
  String url;
  uploadTask.whenComplete(() async {
    url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
  }).catchError((onError) {
    print(onError);
  });
  return url;
}
```

But above code returns following error

> VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception:
> MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method
> Task#startPutFile on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_storage)
> #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:156 
> #1      new MethodChannelTask. (package:firebase_storage_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_task.dart)
>  flutter: MissingPluginException(No
> implementation found for method Reference#getDownloadURL on channel
> plugins.flutter.io/firebase_storage)

I would appreciate if someone could help explain how to resolve this error. Thank you

Comment: do `flutter clean` first then restart `IDE` then do pub get and run

Comment: Thank you so much that resolved the issue for me. I spent a considerable amount of time trying to figure out what could have gone wrong. Thanks a lot. Please post this as answer so I can accept it and other users can benefit from it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing is that you need to do `flutter clean` and then fire the `flutter pub get` command and run your application your issue will solve.

And if still issue persists then do `flutter clean` then `restart your IDE` after that do `flutter pub get` and run your application.